# Deploy struts project in embeded jetty

Tags: struts, jetty

I'm embedding jetty in my application, the structure of the folder tree is:

|--lib
|--WebRoot
      |---WEB-INF
                |---lib

what I wonder is---where should I put the struts2 libs(e.g. struts2-core-2.2.3.1.jar, xwork-core-2.2.3.1.jar), and what about the servlet related api(e.g. servlet-api-2.5-6.1.11.jar, jasper-compiler-5.5.15.jar api)?

should I place jars in the top lib folder or in the lib folder inside WEB-INF?

Answer (score 1):

This is really entirely up to how you want to structure your app, if you are embedding you don't *have* to follow a traditional webapp approach where you have a war file (exploded or not) and its convention of libraries under WEB-INF as in your example with a web.xml, you can skip the idea of a webapp deployer entirely and just build out the handler change yourself and register the servlets in java code, take a look at some of the embedded examples we have:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyServletContexts.java

There are other examples in there as well, if you are embedding then unless you *need* to deploy wars you don't have to muck with that aspect of things.  If you do need to deploy wars then you put things where the would be in any normal usage of a servlet container, things for just that war in the WEB-INF/lib and things in the system classloader back in your main primary classpath.